# How to get a specific link from external webpage and automatically apply clickable event on it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose i have an URL `example.com`, i want read the source of that page and get a particular link like *example1.com* and make a clickable event on it ,means that represents user had click the link from that URL `example.com` to `example1.com`.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to change example,com after reading the source?

Comment: suppose i have link example.com, it contains link example1.com, i want to make clickable event example1.com is clicked automatically from example.com

Comment: The question is still not very clear: Are you saying that you have a site Site.com which has a hyperlink on a page which links to AnotherSite.com and what you want to do is attach an event to that hyperlink so that you can react to the click event?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first make an ajax call to that page to get the content to parse, then parse the webpage content with the link *in your case example.com* then go to the page (with or without click event).

**Requesting Webpage**

You will need some sort of ajax call to get the contents of the webpage for parsing.

[See jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**Parsing**

Get the `#id` or `.class` where the link you need is located (within the parsing function).

[see jQuery Parsing](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/#jQuery-parseHTML-data-context-keepScripts)

**Redirecting**

Click event isn't necessarly needed if you can just redirect to that link when you get it but this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506004/2405689) has both information you need about click/redirecting with JS.

Good luck.